# Issue: FromControl does not show Value

Tags: angular

I have trying to add a value to an input because I need to charge information into a form when it is open, and after of test different ways I've seen that the attribute that makes that value not be showed on angular is `FormControlName`, and it is a form in angular, I can't cut `FormControlName`, so how can I fix it?

```
 <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control form-control-sm"
          id="Name"
          name="Name"
          value="John"
          formControlName="TeamName"
          placeholder="Insert a name"
        />
```

[image]

i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically telling the `input` that you want it to use the `value` `"John"`, but immediately afterwards you tell it "No, please use the form control instead".

Why don't you just set the value directly onto the form control?

```js
export class MyComponent {
  TeamName = new FormControl("John");
}
```

and in the template you say:

```html
<input type="text"
       class="form-control form-control-sm"
       id="Name"
       name="Name"
       [formControl]="TeamName"
       placeholder="Insert a name"/>
```